# How do I draw a plot for my function in R with error ` Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated`?

Tags: r

Following this question: [How to write the denominator summation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597060/how-to-write-the-denominator-summation).

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(100001)
n <- 500

#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n). # generate GOE
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values.   #eigenvalues of GOE with decreasing order
v <- ev$vectors    #eigenvectors of GOE

#size of multivariate distribution  
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)
#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=10, mu=mean, Sigma=var).  # sample ten x_0
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
x_0 <- initial[1, ]/norm(initial[1, ], type="2").   # sample one x_0
```

I try to plot the graph of function `h_1(t)` given in

[image: ![![enter image description here]

where `v_i` are eigenvectors of GOE and `x_0` is the initial vector generated in the above code.

Based on the answer, my code is as follows:

```
h1t <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  numer <- abs(h10) * exp(-2*l[n] * t)
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*l * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  numer/sqrt(denom)
}


plot(h1t, from = 0, to = 100)
```

However, after `t=80`, there would be `NaN` in the function.

```
> h1t(90)
[1] 0.9997982
> h1t(100)
[1] 0
> h1t(400)
[1] NaN
```

The plot:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h_10` in your function is a 1x1 matrix, and this is the source of the warning. You can coerce it to a single number with `c`, or by extracting its `[1, 1]`-entry.

The more serious problem is here:

```r
sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*l * t))
```

If `t` is a single number, there's no problem. But if it is a vector, this expression is mixing some vectors having different length. You have to map the vector `t`, with `sapply` or `vapply` for example:

```r
h1t_modefied <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  numer <- abs(h10) * exp(-2*l[n] * t)
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*l * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  numer/sqrt(denom)
}
```

By the way I don't see the `^2` in your formula in the picture.

```r
> h1t_modefied(1:2)
[1] 0.5734668 0.7033437
> h1t_modefied(1)
[1] 0.5734668
```

If you want to use `curve` you have to use `x` for the variable, not `t`:

```r
curve(h1t_modefied(x), from = 0, to = 20)
```

---

## EDIT

You updated your question, asking why the function is vanishing for large `t`. This is because the exponentials in the sum at the denominator are huge numbers and this sum becomes infinite.

You can improve your function to avoid these huge numbers:

```r
# original function

h1t_A <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  numer <- abs(h10) * exp(-2*l[n] * t)
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*l * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  numer/sqrt(denom)
}

# improved function
h1t_B <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}

# > h1t_A(10)
# [1] 0.8847206
# > h1t_B(10)
# [1] 0.8847206
# > h1t_A(100)
# [1] 0
# > h1t_B(100)
# [1] 0.9949121
# > h1t_B(400)
# [1] 0.9999991
```

The idea is to divide the numerator and the denominator by the exponential term of the numerator.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is a typo in my formula. I have edited it.

Comment: Sorry, can you please see my update? I used your code but the graph is wired. Why there would be `NaN` after `t=80`?

Comment: @oliver `l[i]` becomes negative after `i` approx. 250, then the term `exp(-4*l[i] * .t)` is huge for `.t = 80` and then the sum containing these terms is `Inf`.

Comment: @oliver See my edit, I found a solution.