# How should I change the different size `n=100,200,300,400` so that the `h1t` function of these values `n` are in the same plot?

Tags: r, plot

Following this question:[How do I draw a plot for my function in R with error ` Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74604946/how-do-i-draw-a-plot-for-my-function-in-r-with-error-recycling-array-of-length/74605364?noredirect=1#comment131690274_74605364)

I already have a function `h1t`:

[image]

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(100001)
n <- 500
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)
#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
x_0 <- initial/norm(initial, type="2")

# improved function
h1t <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}

plot(h1t, from = 0, to = 200)
```

The plot for `n=500`:

[image]

I repeat the above code for `n=100`

```
#make this example reproducible
set.seed(100001)
n <- 100
#Sample GOE random matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
ev <- eigen(G)
l <- ev$values
v <- ev$vectors

#size of multivariate distribution
mean <- rep(0, n) 
var <- diag(n)
#simulate bivariate normal distribution
initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
#normalized the first possible initial value, the initial data uniformly distributed on the sphere
x_0 <- initial/norm(initial, type="2")

# improved function
h1t <- function(t) {
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}

plot(h1t, from = 0, to = 200)
```

The plot for `n=100`:

[image]

**Question: How should I change the different size `n=100,200,300,400` so that the `h1t` function of these values `n` are in the same plot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping everything in the function, then using a `for` loop (or `lapply`) to plot the individual lines:

```
h1t <- function(t, n = 500) {
  set.seed(100001)
  A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, mean=0, sd=1), n, n) 
  G <- (A + t(A))/sqrt(2*n)
  ev <- eigen(G)
  l <- ev$values
  v <- ev$vectors
  
  mean <- rep(0, n) 
  var <- diag(n)
  initial <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1, mu=mean, Sigma=var) #ten random vectors
  x_0 <- initial/norm(initial, type="2")
  
  h10 <- c(x_0 %*% v[, n])
  denom <- vapply(t, function(.t) {
    sum((x_0 %*% v)^2 * exp(-4*(l - l[n]) * .t))
  }, numeric(1L))
  abs(h10) / sqrt(denom)
}
```

Create a blank plot and draw the lines:

```
plot(h1t, n = 500, from = 0, to = 200, type = "n") 
for(xx in seq(100, 500, 100)){
  lines(x = seq(0, 200, 1), y = h1t(t = seq(0, 200, 1), n = xx), col = xx/100)
}
legend("bottomright", paste0("n = ",(seq(100, 500, 100))), 
       lty = 1, col = 1:5, bty = "n")

### or lapply
# plot(h1t(t = seq(0, 200, 1), n = 500), type = "n")
# lapply(seq(100, 500, 100), function(x) lines(x = seq(0, 200, 1), 
#                                             y = h1t(t = seq(0, 200, 1), n = x), 
#                                             col = x/100))
# legend("bottomright", paste0("n = ",(seq(100, 500, 100))), 
#       lty = 1, col = 1:5, bty = "n")
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: But when I run `n=100`, it is still a graph of function increasing up to 1. Why your figures are so wired?

Comment: Oh you misunderstood my purpose. We need resampling a random matrix at the beginning for `n=100,200,300,400,500` and compute `h1t` for each `n`. Not fix `n=500` and then choosing `n=100,200` to compute `h1t`.

Comment: That code is that for each random matrix `n*n`, we generate its eigenvectors and a sequence of random vectors `x_0`. Using the expression of `h1t`, we get the plot of `h1t`. So how do we repeat these thing for different value of `n`?

Comment: @oliver see if these edits address your question

Comment: Sorry, do you mean varying from `n=100, 200, 300, 400, 500` from left to right?

Comment: @Oliver I just edited to add a legend to identify what `n` value each line color is representing